# Reading data from text files

Tags: c++, file

I have a question to ask about reading details from text files.

In my text files, I have these information:

```
Employee Name: XXXXXX  
Address: XXXXXXXXXX  
Phone Number: XXXXXX   

Employee Name: XXXXXXXX  
Address: XXXXXXXX  
Phone Number: XXXXXX
```

How can I get everything there is, in the correct format, to be output-ed into the console?

My code is:

```
ifstream inEmpFile;
inEmpFile.open("emp.txt");
string file_contents;

    while(inEmpFile >> file_contents)
    {
        cout << file_contents << ' ';
    }
    inEmpFile.close();
    inEmpFile.clear();
```

All I get is a chunk of text, yes the content is correct, but everything is joined together as in not in the correct format. How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the correct format?

Comment: You should probably take a look at loading the file line by line, and then performing the formatting you look for.

Comment: The one stated above, Employee Name: XXXXX \n Address: XXXXXX. Like that.

Comment: Show both the input format and output format if you want help.

Comment: The output format is already there. above the Code, cause if I do what I did in the code, it goes like this Employee Name: XXXXX Address: XXXXXX Phone Number: XXXXX without skipping lines at each part of the detail

Comment: Are you sure you want to use *code?* Try `cat emp.txt`.

Comment: What kind of computer system are you using? The line separation character(s) varies system by system. In windows, "\r\n" is used. In linux, "\n" is used. In macintosh, "\r" is used.  IF you use windows, replace '\n' to '\r\n' in the file.

Comment: You may better to consider xmls format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just read each line separately using getline() :

```
while (getline(inEmpFile,file_contents))
{
    cout << file_contents << ' '<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getline to get the line from the file to the string. 
Use cout to print the string and follow it by a new line character. 
Do this for every string in the file in a loop.

Comment: Can you please show me an example? I'm still new to C++

Comment: @Yeen: May I suggest looking at all the functions that `ifstream` provides [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/?kw=ifstream)? Also, looking for examples online should be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Using `>>` ignores all the spaces. Copying the entire file can be done this way:

```
ifstream inEmpFile;
inEmpFile.open("emp.txt");

std::cout << inEmpFile.rdbuf(); // no loop needed
```

This works because of a special overload of `<<` for `std::streambuf*` which is returned by `rdbuf()`.

**See (2) stream buffers** [std::ostream::operator<<()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)